# Error in OnBackPressed () xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I'm using xamarin forms where in andorid when I'm on the main page and I click on it back from the error 'An unhandled exception occured.' Does not follow the app lifecycle

I'm trying to do it this way, no results so far ( OnBackPressed )

```
[Activity(Label = "teste", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", NoHistory = true, MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

    }
    bool formOpen = false;
    void OnBackPressed(Bundle bundle)
    {
        if (formOpen == false)
        {
            base.OnBackPressed();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnBackPressed` should be marked as `override` and it is `public`:

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    if (!formOpen)
        base.OnBackPressed();
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It crashes in the other and the error occurs, I think it does not allow the application in the background

Comment: This happens when I'm on the main page

Comment: @José If you are inside of a Form's Page, you should use the lifecycle events within Forms, not the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

use the below

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
```

in the Xamarin forms page, instead of in the android activity.

Comment: Without success, same error when leaving the application of the error